# org mode not producing R plots

Tags: r, emacs, org-mode

I am having problems with **showing** plots in my html output from `org-mode` file. Basically I learnt few months ago how to use org mode for this purpose, and I had a code like this:

```
#+begin_src R :file plot1.png :session :results graphics
 library(lattice)
 xyplot(1:10 ~ 1:10)
#+end_src
```

The code was working perfectly, and the file was created and printed when I exported to html file. Now the exact same code returns `code block produced no output.`; the file is created but not shown in the final html file. I already try several combinations after `#+begin_src R` but with no success. Did something change in the last updates of `org-mode`?. Or where is my problem?

Here is the initial part of my org file

```
#+LANGUAGE:   en
#+STYLE:      <style type="text/css">#outline-container-introduction{ clear:both; }</style>
#+BABEL: :exports both
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran into a similar issue with code that was working and suddenly was not (probably because of upgrading org-mode). This discussion: https://www.mail-archive.com/emacs-orgmode@gnu.org/msg125531.html led to me to discover that now you must list "file" among the ":results" options.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Yes, adding `file` after option `:results` works. Do you have any day how to keep up to date with this details? Last time they change the way categories work and I basically had to fix all my tags. Luckily adding the word "file" in some specific place for all the files is easier, but still extra work. Thanks for the tips!

Comment: I initially read through the change log at https://orgmode.org/Changes.html since I knew I had it working in a previous version of orgmode and the answer is in their documentation, but I wasn't reading it carefully the first time, so I went looking elsewhere. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks,confused me for a long time also! just found they change it with this commit: 26ed66b23 ob: :file and :file-ext no longer imply :results file