# org-mode with R printing code not graphic

Tags: r, emacs, org-mode

I have the following code block.

```
#+begin_src R :file 5.png :session :results graphics file
  library(ggplot2)
  ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = cyl, y = wt)) + geom_point()
#+end_src
```

When I run pdflatex on it, it prints the code, which I don't want, and doesn't insert the file, which I want. What do I need to do?

I thought this seemed relevant, [org mode not producing R plots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59689425/org-mode-not-producing-r-plots), but it doesn't work for me. And the examples here, https://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/babel/languages/ob-doc-R.html, don't seem to work either for me.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing `:exports results`, so the whole file is:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC R :file 5.png :session :results graphics file :exports results
  library(ggplot2)
  ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = cyl, y = wt)) + geom_point()
#+end_src
```

When I export this (`org-export-dispatch` bound by default to `C-c C-e`, then choose `l` for `Latex`, then `o` for `As PDF file and open`), I see a pdf with the plot.

Comment: Ignore my, now deleted comment, saying it didn't work. Apparently the ordering of these arguments really matters. Looks like this does in fact work.